# Toggle Leaflet JS KML layers individually

Tags: leaflet, overlay, layer-switcher

I'm creating a map with multiple KML layers, and have been able to get the KMLs to appear, however, implementing a simple checkbox to turn each layer on and off is proving to be a problem. I've tried omnivore, and several other plugin things, but none seem to work properly.

HTML Toggle:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggleScottsdale" onclick="toggleScottsdale();"><label>&nbsp;SCT AIR</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="toggleSilo" onclick="toggleSilo();"><label>&nbsp;MES SLO</label>
```

Example KML Layer (there are 5 in total):

```
fetch('urltofile1.kml')
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(kmltext => {
            // Create Scottsdale Overlay
            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext, 'text/xml');
            const scottsdale = new L.KML(kml);
            map.addLayer(scottsdale);
        }); 
fetch('urltofile2.kml')
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(kmltext => {
            // Create Silo Overlay
            const parser = new DOMParser();
            const kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext, 'text/xml');
            const scottsdale = new L.KML(kml);
            map.addLayer(silo);
        });
```

Toggle Function:

```
function toggleScottsdale() {
        if(map.addLayer(scottsdale)) {
            map.removeLayer(scottsdale);
        } else {
            map.addLayer(scottsdale);
        }
    }; 
function toggleSilo() {
        if(map.addLayer(silo)) {
            map.removeLayer(silo);
        } else {
            map.addLayer(silo);
        }
    };
```

Not only does console return that `scottsdale` is undefined, but I am unsure how to replicate a toggle for each layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution would be to store KML overlays in some global object, using overlay name as property name, and then use general `toggleOverlay` function that add/removes overly to the map on the basis of checkbox id that corresponds to overlay name.

Code could then look something like this:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="scottsdale" onclick="toggleOverlay(this)" checked><label>&nbsp;SCT AIR</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="silo" onclick="toggleOverlay(this)" checked><label>&nbsp;MES SLO</label>
```

JS

```
var overlays = {};

function toggleOverlay(checkbox) {
  var overlay = overlays[checkbox.id];
  if (map.hasLayer(overlay)) {
    if (!checkbox.checked) map.removeLayer(overlay);
    }
  else if (checkbox.checked) {
    map.addLayer(overlay);
  }
}

fetch('urltofile1.kml')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(kmltext => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext, 'text/xml');
    const scottsdale = new L.KML(kml);
    map.addLayer(scottsdale);
    overlays['scottsdale'] = scottsdale;
  }); 
fetch('urltofile2.kml')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(kmltext => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const kml = parser.parseFromString(kmltext, 'text/xml');
    const silo = new L.KML(kml);
    map.addLayer(silo);
    overlays['silo'] = silo;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for that - this was one of the initial solutions I had found elsewhere, but when I implement it, nothing happens but an error message in the console:
`(index):103 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at toggleOverlay ((index):103:35)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):31:77)`

Comment: I implemented your version and got the same result, I thin I'm still missing some things - and have updated the question to include the entire script

Comment: You have `toggleOverlay` function defined twice. In the second definition (which prevails) you are using condition `if (!checkbox.unchecked) map.removeLayer(overlay)`. Property `unchecked` does not exist.

Comment: I've been staring at this stuff too long - I sure did, thanks for pointing that out! After removing the second `var overlays` and `toggleOverlay` function, I'm still getting that error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') at toggleOverlay ((index):42:35) at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):29:77)`

Comment: Ups, sorry, missing parameter `this` when specifying `onclick` handler. See modified answer.

Comment: You are right! I missed that too, my apologies - and thank you so very much, this is now working!

Comment: I rolled back your last edit to the question so that answer matches the question.